# AngularFire2 authentication with CanActivate not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angularfire2

Angular 2 RC6 using AngularFire2.  My authentication works which causes a redirect to a guarded route ("/feed").  When the canActivate method in the AuthGuard fires, authentication is always null.  It seems as if authentication happens before the guard is ever constructed, so the subscribe in the guard does nothing.

login.ts (this authentication works and redirects to 'feed')

```
constructor(public af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {
  this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => console.log(auth));
}
login() {
  this.af.auth.login({
    provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
    method: AuthMethods.Popup,
  }).then((x: FirebaseAuthState) => {
    console.log(x);
    this.router.navigate(['/feed']);
  }).catch(x => console.log(x));
}
```

feed.routes.ts

```
export const feedRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FeedComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];
```

auth-guard.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }             from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router,
        ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        RouterStateSnapshot }    from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFire, AngularFireAuth, FirebaseAuthState }            from 'angularfire2';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  auth: FirebaseAuthState;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {
    console.log('auth guard constructed');
    this.af.auth.subscribe(authState => console.log(authState));
    this.af.auth.subscribe(x => this.auth = x);
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log('can activate ' + this.auth)
    if (this.auth == null){
      // this part always fires
      console.log('no auth!')
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    } 
      console.log('authenticated');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Here is what is printed to the console:

```
Object {auth: W, uid: "xYFs8kMDpKdYKxDw4AL21FtnSWn1", provider: 2, facebook: Of}
auth-guard.service.ts:13 auth guard constructed
auth-guard.service.ts:19 can activate undefined
auth-guard.service.ts:21 no auth!
```

Notice the actions in the .subscribe never occur.

Comment: I would look closely at the order of the `console.log` calls you have in the login and the guard. If the former is first, the guard will have received the emitted auth state after the routing, which would explain the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put my console output, I've added it to the question

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    console.log("canActivate");
    return this.af.auth.take(1).map(auth => {
      console.log("auth:" + auth);
      if (!auth) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        return true;
      }
      return !!auth;
    });
  }
```

But the auth observable is not firing for me either.

Comment: If the `auth` observable is not emitting anything, I'd suggest [raising an issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues), as the `AngularFireAuth` observable is a [`ReplaySubject` with a buffer size of 1](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts#L30-L35), so it should be emitting a value.

Comment: thanks for the example, wouldn't I want to return false if !auth though?

Comment: Hmm, that is probably true, I don't remember if making that false blocks the navigation though... and I can't get the observable to fire now.

Comment: So the issue is angularfire2 doesn't work with RC6 @RyanLangton, see: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/493